# Selecting a Line in a Window canvas image

Tags: lazarus

I want user to be able to select a line in an image to swap or rotate the line.  There are vertical and horizontal lines and text on the terminated lines.  These lines make a rectangular tree and need to be be able have user select a new root on the tree.  So far I'm just using LineTo, MoveTo,  and TextOut to make the tree.  These don't appear to be selectable when the program is running.  Can a setting be changed or does each line need to be inserted as a separate object?  I would rather not use a third party software since the application must be distributed freely.  I'm trying to limit myself to built in controls.  I tried using paint box but it doesn't have scroll bars.

Comment: A canvas is no different than a paper, what is drawn is not a line anymore but part of an image. You have to erase and redraw to relocate anything.

Comment: I was hoping there was drawing control something like a stripped down AutoCAD that you select a line and not allow them to edit.  I need the user able to select a line so it will change where the drawing starts or the root of the tree is.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be 4 red apple and 1 yellow apple drawings.  You want the user to be able to move yellow apple among the red apples.  Clicking one of the read apple drawings would swap with yellow apple drawing.

Comment: I understand your requirement. A canvas is really, truly like a real life canvas. Once you paint an orange on it, you can't move it anywhere. You can erase (paint) the entire canvas and paint the orange to a different place. If you can use 'TShape's, that would be OK - in the sense that they are moveable, you still have to write code to do it at runtime. Otherwise you either have to use third party software, or write similar functionality yourself.